# Visual Basic- Random Numbers

Tags: vb.net, random

I'm trying to generate 5 random numbers from 1-99 and display them in a ListBox.  Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?  Right now my code is displaying all 99 numbers in the ListBox, but I only want 5 of them to display.  Here is the code:

```
'list to store numbers
        Dim numbers As New List(Of Integer)

        'add desired numbers to list
        For count As Integer = 1 To 99
            numbers.Add(count)
        Next


        Dim Rnd As New Random
        Dim SB As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        Dim Temp As Integer

        'select a random number from the list, add to listbox and remove it so it can't be selected again
        For count As Integer = 0 To numbers.Count - 1
            Temp = Rnd.Next(0, numbers.Count)
            SB.Append(numbers(Temp) & "  ")
            ListBox2.Items.Add(numbers(Temp))
            numbers.RemoveAt(Temp)
        Next
```

Comment: Are you sure you know how the loops work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
For count As Integer = 0 To numbers.Count - 1
```

With

```
For count As Integer = 1 To 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The above will work but, You need to add count just after your next statement as well. I recommend checking into learning more about loops as well. Clearly Visual Basic 2012 is great for that.